# How to edit Select tag in Laravel Collective?

Tags: php, laravel, forms, select, laravelcollective

I want to edit the task_status select but I get an invalid foreach() argument error. The format follows similarly to other forms from the Laravel Collective.

```
{{Form::select('task_status', $task->task_status, [ 'On Hold'=> 'On Hold', 'Completed'=> 'Completed'], ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
```

Comment: What do you want to edit exactly. How are you doing to get error. Can you explain what do you want to do better?

Comment: {{Form::select('task_status', [ 'On Hold'=> 'On Hold', 'Completed'=> 'Completed'], $task->task_status, ['class' => 'form-control'])}} ? Your sequence for parameter is wrong..i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> invalid foreach() argument error.

This will occur only when you dont pass the values for populating the dropdown

So You need to know the arguments

```
function select(
        $name,
        $list = [],
        $selected = null,
        array $selectAttributes = [],
        array $optionsAttributes = [],
        array $optgroupsAttributes = []
    )
```

> First Argument => 'name of the select tag' in Your case its
>   `task_status`
>
> Second  Argument => 'Dropdown Values List ' in Your case its `[ 'On
>   Hold'=> 'On Hold', 'Completed'=> 'Completed']`
>
> Third Argument => 'the selected option(s) ' in Your case its
>   `$task->task_status` (Used while editing)
>
> Fourth  Argument => 'optional Attributes ' in Your case its `['class'
>   => 'form-control']`

So the final function may look like

```
{!!Form::select('task_status',[ 'On Hold'=> 'On Hold', 'Completed'=> 'Completed'],$task->task_status,['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
```

If You are using

`Form::model()` 
to populate the values while editing you don't need to add 
`$task->task_status`

to the select tag it will be automatically loaded

**ONLY WHILE EDITING**

Answer (score 0):

As stated in their [documentation](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/docs/blob/5.6/html.md#generating-a-drop-down-list-with-selected-default), you need to place the select option values **before** the default selected value of the drop down list.

Therefore, this would be the correct syntax:

```
{{Form::select('task_status', [ 'On Hold' => 'On Hold', 'Completed' => 'Completed'], $task->task_status, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
```